# Why does "grep -w" match strings ending with "." or "$"?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

1.) I am using Debian 8.4 on a virtual box and lets say I have a text file name sample.txt containing..

```
Linux. 
Linux$
```

Then I ran the command `grep -w Linux sample.txt` and the output was

```
Linux.
Linux$
```

So I was wondering why it match those lines since I specified the -w option which is supposed to match the exact string only?

Comment: I think you want `grep -x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `$` and `.` are non-word constituent characters, so `-w` matches `Linux` in both lines, nothing else.

[`man grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) states that:

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The
>   test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of
>   the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly,
>   it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word
>   constituent character. **Word-constituent characters are letters,
>   digits, and the underscore**. This option has no effect if -x is also
>   specified.

This means that `Linux` will be matched in all cases where this text is surrounded by anything but letters, digits and the underscore.

To see what exactly is `grep` matching, use `-o` to print the matched part only:

```
$ echo "Linux.
Linux$" | grep -wo Linux
Linux
Linux
```

So it is just  `Linux` what gets matched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the reference as well!

Answer (score 1):

Option `-w` has the semantics of matching "whole words".  A word delimiter is a change of character class, e. g. from letter to symbol or to interpunction, so `x$` contains a word delimiter between the two characters, so does `x.`.